# Elixir module property causing ArgumentError

Tags: module, elixir, constants

Why does using a module constant:

```
defmodule A do
    @tab :binary.compile_pattern("\t")

    def run do
        :binary.match("hello\tworld", @tab)
    end
end
```

give the error:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :binary.match("hello\tworld", {:bm, ""})
             iex:4: A.run/0
```

but moving `@tab` to a regular variable inside `run/0` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiled binary patterns are runtime values. As such they can't pass the compile-time (as assigned in module attribute) and runtime barrier. This means they can't be stored in module attributes.

Particularly, binary patterns are implemented as NIF resources - they are represented in Erlang as empty binaries, but underneath is usually some raw data used by native code. When passing from compile-time to runtime only the empty binary remains - all additional data (that is needed here) is lost.